# Turning LED on in Nucleo 64 F103RB via Registers

Tags: c, stm32, gpio

I have a STM32 NUCLEO-64 F103RB and I am using Keil uVision 5. I was just testing the device with CubeMX software and was able to blink or turn on the green LED in my device. I then decided to do the same by changing the values in the registers on the board in C code directly. This is an schematic of the device:

[image]

Where I have highlited the GPIO A and the Bus that connects to the referred port. According to my understanding, two things should be done before actually turning the LED on:
1 - Activating the clock for the APB2 bus
2 - Setting the GPIOA Port 5 (which corresponds to the LED) to output mode.

I have done these two steps. However, the LED still won't turn on. I've tried looking at the documentation and found that the PA5 could be used as SPI, and I tried to change the register AFIO_MAPR (Page 184 of the reference manual) but that also didn't work. I tried looking at the clock activation for AHB2, but I didn't quite understand how it would work.
My C code is:

```
#include "stm32f10x.h"                  // Device header


int main() {
// Initialise clock of APB2 Bus
    RCC->APB2ENR = (RCC->APB2ENR & 0x0) | RCC_APB2ENR_IOPAEN;

// Put the GPIOA in Output mode
    GPIOA->CRL = (GPIOA->CRL & 0x44444444) | GPIO_CRL_MODE5_1;


// Changinging the ODR Register (Lighting the LED)
    while(1) {
    GPIOA->ODR = (GPIOA->ODR & 0x0) | GPIO_ODR_ODR5;
    }

}
```

[Nucleo64 F103RB Reference Manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/59/b9/ba/7f/11/af/43/d5/CD00171190.pdf/files/CD00171190.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00171190.pdf)

[Nucleo64 F103RB User Manual](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/98/2e/fa/4b/e0/82/43/b7/DM00105823.pdf/files/DM00105823.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00105823.pdf)

Comment: Are you sure the output is "active high"?

Comment: That should be assured by the changing in the ODR register, I suppose.

Comment: Try both senses. Try writing all 1's or all 0's to the port.

Comment: I tried writing 0 and then 1 to all the 15 bits in the register. None of the options worked.

Comment: not using STM definitions is the best way to get into the troubles. Good people from STM have given names to all of those bits.

Comment: Yeah. I'm aware, I was just testing. I'll try to write a little better code see if it works, and if not i'll update the question.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the code and it still doesn't work. I have updated the question.

Comment: you do strange things

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209873/discussion-between-vitor-c-goergen-and-p-j).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What step?

1. Enable GPIOA clock.
2. Configure pin to be push-pull output.
3. Toggle the pin.

For general GPIO do not set any AFIOs.

```
RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_IOPAEN;
__DSB();
  GPIOA -> CRL &= ~GPIO_CRL_CNF5_Msk;
  GPIOA -> CRL |= GPIO_CRL_MODE5_Msk;

  while(1)
  {
      GPIOA -> ODR ^= GPIO_ODR_ODR5;
      for(volatile unsigned x = 0; x < 500000; x++);
  }
```

you need also to check the solder bridges on the board:
[image]

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't see which one of these steps I am not doing.

Comment: Apparently, I was missing the CNF line. Cannot believe I forgot this. Thank you.

Comment: @VitorCGoergen you forgot about small delay after enabling the clock. It is very important. In your code the first GPIO register write may fail.